# Help with Relational Predication Logic

Tags: predicate-logic

13. Translate into predicate form. (Relational predication is required.)

Every animal lives somewhere. Mars lives nowhere. So, Mars is not animal.

[A = “is a animal”, L = “lives”, P = “is a place”, M = m “Mars” N = nowhere]

∀x(Ax⟶∃y(Py & Lxy),  ∃x(Lx  &  Nmx)  ⊢ ∼Am

14. Translate into predicate form. (Relational predication is required.)

Gluons look like nothing. Everything looks like itself. Hence, there are no gluons.

[G = “gluons”, L = “look like”, I = “itself”,

∀x(Gx⟶∀y∼Lxy) or ∀x(Gx⟶∼∃y Lxy),  ∀x(Lx⟶Ix) ⊢ ∼∃xGx

I need help because I am not entirely sure if my translation is correct so any help would be great. Here is an example of correct relational predication translation to help anyone who may be confused.

[Relational Predication Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sPcY.png)

Comment: See the answer to your previous posts for detailed instructions.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

13:

- Your second statement is unclear. What does $\exists x$ introduce - why having an existential introduction in addition when you are already using a constant name for Mars? Why is $L$ suddenly a one-place predicate when it was tro-place in the first statement? What exactly is the relation $N$ expresses between the two arguments it takes? **In general, when giving the translation keys, you should always include all of the arguments the predicate symbol takes, to make clear which argument takes over which role in the relation**: e.g. "$Ax$ = x is an animal, $Lxy$ = x lives at y, ..."
- If you formalize "x lives somewhere" as $\exists y (Py \land Lxy)$, then it makes sense to formalize "x lives nowhere" as $\neg \exists y (Py \land Lxy)$. With the first argument to the living-relation ("x") being mars ($m$), your second sentence reads $\neg \exists y(Py \land Lmy)$ (= "There is no thing y such that y is a place and Mars lives at it").
- You could actually omit the place predicate altogether (since "place" doesn't occur in the original English sentence either) and just go with "There is a/no thing such that x lives at it": $\forall x(Ax \to \exists y Lxy), \neg \exists y (Lmy)$.
- Also, are you sure you are supposed to use "$\vdash$" B convention, this means derivability in a formal system, but I suppose you rather want to express logical consequence (the right-hand side logically follows from the left-hand size), which is symbolized as "$\vDash$", or a simple "therefore", as used in syllogisms, which is symbolized as "∴".
- With this, 13 will be:
  $Ax$ = "$x$ is an animal", $Lxy$ = "$x$ lives at $y$", $m$ = "Mars"
  $\forall x(Ax \to \exists y Lxy), \neg \exists y Lmy) ∴ \neg Am$.

14:

- Again, include the predicate arguments in your translations: "$Gx$ = x is a gluon, $Lxy$ = x looks like y, ..."
- There are similar issues with your second sentence as in 13: Why is $L$ now a one-place predicate when it used to be 2-place in the first sentence? What exactly does $Ix$ mean - $x$ is itself? Right now, your second sentence reads "For all x it holds that if it looks like, then it is itself". Instead, You want to express that the look-like relation is reflexive, i.e. that for all x, x looks like x: $\forall x(Lxx)$. You don't need a predicate $I$ for that, but instead express the "itself" by referencing the same variable ($x$).
- So 14 will be 
  $Gx$ = "$x$ is a gluon", $Lxy$ = "$x$ looks like $y$"
  $\forall x(Gx \to \neg \exists y Lxy), \forall x(Lxx) ∴ \neg \exists x Gx$.